# paginating unlimited S3 size with filters

Tags: amazon-s3, lambda, aws-lambda, boto3

in my bucket, S3 has an unlimited number of objects whose names are the epoch value in which they were created. (e.g. "1503379525")
The Lambda function should concatenate the contents of all files between a specific time range (last 15 minutes).

My solution is to use:

- Pagination to get a list of objects
- page_iterator.search("Contents[?Key > `epoch-for-last-15-min`][]")

I need to consider the memory limit of Lambda and need to make sure the paginator works fine in a bucket with an unlimited number of files. 
Is this a feasible solution?

Comment: Lambda cannot do anything genuinely "unlimited" -- runtime, CPU cores and cycles, memory, and temporary disk space are all finite resources.

Comment: I know, that's why I am looking for a feasible solution.

Comment: [AWS Batch](https://aws.amazon.com/batch/) might be worth investigating.  It looks like overkill at first glance, but like most things AWS, it appears to be able to scale from really large to very small.

Comment: Alternatively, you could send your data to Amazon Kinesis Firehose and have it save data based upon time periods or data volumes. It would create the output files without having to concatenate existing files.